# How to Get value with name by Dom

Tags: php, html

Hy friends I am using this method to get all href links from  tag from a site

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
    @$DOM->loadHTML($data);
    @$links = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($links as $link){
        $url = $link->getAttribute('href');
echo $url;
```

Now I don't know how to get the value by name fb_dtsg ..... Here is the source code

```
<input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQF0dSiG6Lyr:AQEnJP0PhWzy" autocomplete="off" />
```

I want to get it's value with DOm how to do this...... Thanks in advance

Comment: Before downvoting please give me answer ..... Why you downvote me... Reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DOMXpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)'s query method to get elements by the name attribute.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML($data);
@$links = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$input = $xpath->query('//input[@name="fb_dtsg"]');

echo $input[0]->getAttribute('value');
```

This will print the value of the first input element with name 'fb_dtsg'.

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you need to know anything more.

Answer (score 1):

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML($data);
@$links = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach($inputs as $input) {
     if ($input->getAttribute('name') == 'fb_dtsg') {
         echo 'found, do whatever';
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$DOM->getElementsByTagName('a'); // for tag name


$DOM->getElementsByName('fb_dtsg'); // for name


document.getElementById('fb_dtsg_id').value // for showing value of the field
```

Comment: Well it works fine. I did many times. 
for your reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementsbyname_length

Comment: Bro but this doesn't echo value from this html code.  <input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQF0dSiG6Lyr:AQEnJP0PhWzy" autocomplete="off" />

Comment: oh sorry. 
For that you need to do `document.getElementById('fb_dtsg').value`

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? What I got it. YOu have a html form field. and you want its value in a php variable ? right ? 
On same page or with form submit or what else ?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath` for that.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$elementByName = $xpath->query("//input[@name='fb_dtsg']");

...
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/class.domxpath.php